# Azure SignalR .NET Framework C# Client cannot authenticate

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, signalr

I am trying to connect a C# .NET 4.7 application as a client to my Azure SignalR service. I am using the ASP.NET version of the SignalR client library, NOT the ASP.NET CORE version.

I have code set up like this:

```
var serviceUtils = new ServiceUtils(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Azure:SignalR:ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

var url = $"{utils.Endpoint}/client/";

_connection = new HubConnection(url, $"?hub={hubName}")
{
    ConnectionToken = serviceUtils.GenerateAccessToken(url, userId)
};

IHubProxy proxy = _connection.CreateHubProxy(hubName);

await _connection.Start().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

However, this does not work. I get back a 'StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized'' when _connection.Start() throws an exception.

The "ServiceUtils" token generation is pulled from the example here:

https://github.com/vavjeeva/AzureSignalRConsoleApp/blob/master/AzureSignalRConsoleApp.Utils/ServiceUtils.cs

Interestingly, I have implemented the same logic in a basic C# .Net Core console app, using the .Net Core version of the library, and it actually does work, using the same connection string. The difference is I am using the HubConnectionBuilder, which does not exist in the asp.net version of the library. My assumption is that the two are authenticating in different ways.

How do I get this sort of functionality working in this version of the library? I want my service application, as a client, to be able to invoke hubu methods via the Azure SignalR Service.